# using JQuery to change a second drop down selection box from mysql DB

Tags: jquery, mysql, select

I am trying to get the second dropdown box to change and populate when the first box has a car Make chosen. It connects to the database just fine, and if I type 'Honda' instead of 'carmake3' in the second dropdown, then it gives me a list of all the honda cars. I just need to work based on what the user selects. Any help would be extremely appreciated!

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<form action="step-3" method="post">
Car 3
</div>

<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', '**********', '**********');
mysql_select_db('**********');
$sql = "SELECT Make FROM CarMakes";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='carmake3'>";
 echo "<option value='Make'>Make</option>"; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Make'] . "'>" . $row['Make'] . "</option>";}
echo "</select>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('carmodel3').change(function() {
        jQuery('carmake3').change();
    });
});
</script>

<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', '**********', '**********');
mysql_select_db('**********');
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Make='carmake3'";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
echo "<select name='carmodel3'>";
  echo "<option value='Model'>Model</option>"; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  echo "<option value='" . $row['Model'] . "'>" . $row['Model'] . "</option>";}
echo "</select>";
?>
<input type="text" maxlength="4" name="car3year" placeholder="year" class="WriteInBox"/>

<input type="text" maxlength="6" name="car3miles" placeholder="miles" class="WriteInBox"/>

</div>

</form>
```

Comment: so many things needs to be corrected..

Comment: please help me out. some tips. or if you want to redo it for me I would appreciate that

Comment: well i would love to but SO is not meant for that...you need to contact me on `elance` for that.

Comment: I just posted a job and invited you. let me know if you dont get it. I need this done ASAP

Comment: well you have answer too...

Comment: please share your database structure here...so i can help you more...

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36294/jquery-drop-down  join me here

Answer (score 0):

Do a html as given below for Make

```
$sql = "SELECT Make FROM CarMakes";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
<select id="carmake3" name='carmake3' onchange="get_makes();">
<option value='Make'>Make</option>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Make'] . "'>" . $row['Make'] . "</option>";}
?>
</select>
<div id="get_car_make"></div> // Sub will be appended here using ajax
```

Write a ajax function get_makes();

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_makes() { // Call to ajax function
    var carmake3 = $('#carmake3').val();
    var dataString = "carmake3="+carmake3+"&redirecturl="+redirecturl;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getcarmakenames.php", // Name of the php files
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#get_car_make").html(html);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

File getcarmakenames.php - Will get sub from the below file which will be appended to the div

```
if ($_POST) {
    $carmake3 = $_POST['carmake3'];
    if ($carmake3 != '') {
       $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Make='carmake3'";
       $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
       echo "<select name='carmodel3'>";
       echo "<option value='Model'>Model</option>"; 
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
          echo "<option value='" . $row['Model'] . "'>" . $row['Model'] . "</option>";}
       echo "</select>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo  '';
    }
}
```